# Ensure Link List is Freed

Tags: c, list, memory-management, linked-list

Below is a simple program that creates a frees a linked list. However, I am unsure whether the free_list function ensures all the allocated memory is freed.

Here is the main function, which simply calls the other two functions:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct node *head = build_list();
    free_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

build_list() creates a simple, three membered list:

```
struct node *build_list()
{
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *two = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *three = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 0;
    head->next = two;

    two->data = 1;
    two->next = three;

    three->data = 2;
    three->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

and free_list() attempts to free each member of the list in sequence:

```
void free_list(struct node *curr)
{
    struct node *tmp;

    while (curr) {
        tmp = curr;
        curr = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not this frees all allocated memory. It appears as if it should, but I am unsure whether or not the use *tmp could cause a block of memory to remain allocated. And finally, any advice on the best practices for freeing a linked list would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

For reference, here is the node struct:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unsure whether or not the use *tmp could cause a block of memory to remain allocated.

No, it cannot. There are no constructs in C that would allow dynamically allocated memory to stay around after being freed explicitly through the call of `free()`.

At the end of your function `tmp` indeed points to the location of the last node. However, at this point it's a *dangling pointer*, so it causes no harm.

> any advice on the best practices for freeing a linked list would be much appreciated.

What you have is the classic program for freeing a liked list.
The only modification to consider here is declaring `tmp` it inside loop's body, since it is not used outside the loop:

```
while (curr) {
    struct node * tmp = curr;
    curr = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Which method, if any, is preferred for freeing a list? Also, should tmp be set to NULL so it is not a dangling pointer, or is that unnecessary?

Comment: @wm For singly-linked list there's only one reasonable method of freeing - the one you coded up. One could also code a recursive one, but that would be an abuse of recursion.